# how do I get all text separated in nested div under 1 element ID

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium

Monitoring tab under parent link:
http://www.pajak.go.id/statistik-amnesti

Using Python, I am trying to extract the top left table on https://monitoringamnesti.pajak.go.id/viewer/dashboard?dashboardguid=90a16bf8-d418-4ed4-8160-7f883f601dd0&v=636126392121123334&style=Default

My code:

```
import selenium.webdriver as driver

browser = driver.Chrome()  

url=  "https://monitoringamnesti.pajak.go.id/viewer/public/dashboard?name=Monitoring_Amnesti_Pajak"

browser.get(url)

all_text = browser.execute_script("returndocument.getElementById('SimpleDataGrid-viewport').textContent")
```

However all text is lumped together. Is there a way I can get all information in the table as a list/dataframe?

HTML Code:

```
<div id="SimpleDataGrid-viewport" class="datagrid-viewport" style="width: 120px; height: 376px;">
<div id="SimpleDataGrid-spacer-clip" class="datagrid-spacer-clip clip _hidden" style="width: 22px; height: 23px;">
    <div id="SimpleDataGrid-spacer" class="datagrid-spacer" style="width: 22px; height: 23px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell blank" style="border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 153, 195); width: 22px; height: 11px;">&nbsp;
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="SimpleDataGrid-head-clip" class="datagrid-head-clip clip" style="width: 120px; margin-left: 0px; height: 23px;">
<div id="SimpleDataGrid-head" class="datagrid-head" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 552px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell column0 text sortable" data-type="text" data-index="0" data-sortorder="unsorted" style="border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 153, 195); width: 161px; height: 11px;">Jenis<em class="unsorted" data-sortorder="unsorted"></em>
        </div>
        <div class="cell column1 number sortable" data-type="number" data-index="1" data-sortorder="unsorted" style="border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 153, 195); width: 52px; height: 11px;">Juli<em class="unsorted" data-sortorder="unsorted"></em>
        </div>
        <div class="cell column2 number sortable" data-type="number" data-index="2" data-sortorder="unsorted" style="border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 153, 195); width: 58px; height: 11px;">Agustus<em class="unsorted" data-sortorder="unsorted"></em>
        </div>
        <div class="cell column3 number sortable" data-type="number" data-index="3" data-sortorder="unsorted" style="border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 153, 195); width: 73px; height: 11px;">September<em class="unsorted" data-sortorder="unsorted"></em></div>
        <div class="cell column4 number sortable" data-type="number" data-index="4" data-sortorder="unsorted" style="border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 153, 195); width: 58px; height: 11px;">Oktober<em class="unsorted" data-sortorder="unsorted"></em>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you post the relevant HTML code? The link you mentioned in the question is asking for login credentials.

Comment: Hi, I have added the main link in there. Copying the html code in here seems too long and messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sudharsan mentioned, the URL you provided requests login credentials, so we can't see the content you reference.

If you want to use Selenium to do this, then rather than simply asking selenium to execute Javascript, you'll need to instruct Selenium to pull the table of interest, then output that to whatever form is of interest to you.

based on the code you have provided, I'm guessing that you could work out something to meet your needs by looking at this, where the css selector is finding all of the "columns" in each row of the grid:

```
# print the content of each row in the table (this will include the headers)
for cell in browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[id='SimpleDataGrid-head'] div.row div.cell"):
    print(cell.text)
```

Comment: If your "table" isn't a "table" element with "tr" rows, then if you can provide us with output showing the first few rows, we can probably help you come up with a path to identify the rows.

Comment: Thanks for your help. the table isnt a table element however. I have added part of the html there.

Comment: I've edited my answer above with a css selector to find all of the cells.  You could break that up to two loops, where the first loop looks for "rows" using the selector "div[id='SimpleDataGrid-head'] div.row", then for each row, output the cells using row.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.cell")

Comment: cool @j.j .  Glad that it worked for you.  Would you mind accepting the answer?